# String to SOAPMessage not working in java

Tags: java, web-services, soapui, saaj

I have below message in a String,

```
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:def="http://DefaultNamespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <def:XXX soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in0 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">someEncryptedTextGoesHere</in0>
      </def:XXX>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

I'm trying to convert it in **SOAPMessage and access its body in order to get the EncryptedText, but for some reason envelop gets null**, I don't understand 
I tried with,

1)  Basically I have HttpEntity, and body of a entity is a soaprequest

```
public String getEncryptedCodeFromSOAPRequest(HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity) throws SOAPException, IOException {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity.getBody());
    log.info(requestEntity.getBody().toString());
    String encryptedCode = "";
    if (is.available() > 0) {
        //SOAPMessage request= MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
        SOAPMessage request = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,is);
        encryptedCode = new String(request.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeValue().getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
    return encryptedCode;
}
```

2) Tried using different kinds of SOAPConstants like,

```
SOAPMessage request = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.URI_NS_SOAP_1_1_ENVELOPE).createMessage(null,is);
```

URI_NS_SOAP_1_1_ENVELOPE using this because xmlns:soapenv in soap msg seems to be like this dont know it this login correct or not.

Please let me know if you have suggestion on this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting a debug breakpoint on the line that has `request.getSOAPBody()` and see whats in `request.getSOAPBody()`?  Also, try and printout whats in `request.getSOAPBody()` as a System.out.println *Prior* to trying to work with it.  It may help you to find out where you might be going wrong, The debug especially, it might show your values elsewhere, you might also need to tgreat it differently like instead of getting the node value, get its text

Comment: I tried both of them, with printing request.getBody().toString() print the soap message in [sqare bracket] and with debug as well it shows the value properly

Comment: If I try to print request.getBody().toString().length  it's printing only 11, M I doing something wrong by toString here

Comment: If this isnt a typo ` request.getBody().toString().length` it might be printing the length of the body address/memory reference, e.g. if you dont print the length and do toString on it you'd probably see what I mean.  I think you need `request.getSOAPBody().length` ;-)

Comment: :/ I corrected it to new String(requestEntity.getBody()) but still no luck :(

Comment: What is the length of this `request.getSOAPBody()` and then this `request.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild()` and then this `request.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getFirstChild()`.  Also print each one out in trace and add to your question above through edit. Oh, and just saw the image, checking.  That image is from the soap envelope, much is null, what if you do the same for this `requestEntity.getBody()` and `request.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild()` and show pictures like above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164708/discussion-between-tyro-and-jglass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
if (is.available() > 0) {
    //SOAPMessage request= MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
    SOAPMessage request = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,is);
    encryptedCode = new String(request.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeValue().getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

With This:

```
    if (is.available() > 0) {
        SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance("SOAP 1.2 Protocol").createMessage(null, is);
        Document requestDocument = message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument();
        NodeList nodes = requestDocument.getChildNodes();
        //get parent node 1
        Node parentNode = nodes.item(0);
        //get child nodes, of parent node
        NodeList childNodes = parentNode.getChildNodes();
        //get first child node since theres only one in the example xml
        Node childNode = childNodes.item(0);
        //print type, value, etc
        System.out.println(childNode.getNodeType() + " = " + childNode.getNodeName() + "/" + childNode.getNodeValue());
        encryptedCode = childNode.getNodeValue();
    }
```

Comment: It didnt work too same issue of empty envelop :(, So I did it by splitting the string

Comment: The envelope doesnt matter, this `Document requestDocument = message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument();` get rid of the SOAP Envelope, which you dont need anyways, you want the SOAP body which the above should have given.  Did you check during debug at each point in the above code if you were receiving the data you expected to be there?  Either way, if it works for you thats all that matters - just keep in mind it will slow things down in a production environment.

Comment: the issue was of new line characters in the string of xml. so if I remove the new line character I would get the node value  from first child of childnode, I'm modifying the answer lil bit. But thanks once again. and in this case SOAPMessage  from MEssagefactory would also work properly